# How to use WinForms/WPF as ActiveX control?

Tags: wpf, winforms, activex

I would like to use WinForms/WPF controls as if they were ActiveX controls.

Specifically I would like to host these controls inside SAP Business One or it may be outside
of SAP B1.

Is this possible at all? If yes, I would like to see some examples.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The machine running SAP Business One will still need the .NET framework, of course, but yes, you can expose your controls as ActiveX objects.

Have a look at this article: [WPF Vista Gadgets using ActiveX](https://web.archive.org/web/20140423132544/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karstenj/archive/2006/10/09/activex-wpf-gadget.aspx). Referenced in that article is a [sample WPF ActiveX control](http://winfx.members.winisp.net/files/activexgadget.zip). That should get you started.

Comment: The second link is broken.

Comment: Seeing as how that article is 7 years old, you can't blame them. The original article has a busted link as well.